# Timezone problem with spark.sql time functions

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timezone

i'm writing some code on a jupyter notebook using spark 2.4.7 and pyspark running in Standalone Mode.
I need to convert some timestamps to unix time to do some operations however i noticed a strange behavior,following the code i'm running:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("test") \
        .master(n_spark_master)\
        .config("spark.total.executor.cores",n_spark_cores_max)\
        .config("spark.cores.max", n_spark_cores_max)\
        .config("spark.executor.memory",n_spark_executor_memory)\
        .config("spark.executor.cores",n_spark_executor_cores)\
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()

print(datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo)

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "a"),
    (2, "b"),
    (3, "c"), ], ["dummy1", "dummy2"])

epoch = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) df=df.withColumn('epoch',lit(epoch))  
timeFmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'  
df= df.withColumn('unix_time_epoch',F.unix_timestamp('epoch', format=timeFmt)) df.show()
```

output:

```
CET
+------+------+-------------------+---------------+
|dummy1|dummy2|              epoch|unix_time_epoch|
+------+------+-------------------+---------------+
|     1|     a|1970-01-01 00:00:00|          -3600|
|     2|     b|1970-01-01 00:00:00|          -3600|
|     3|     c|1970-01-01 00:00:00|          -3600|
+------+------+-------------------+---------------+
```

from documentation of spark 2.4.7:

> pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp(timestamp=None, format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')[source]
> Convert time string with given pattern (‘yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss’, by default) to Unix time stamp (in seconds), using **the default timezone and the default locale**, return null if fail.

The previous command `print(datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo)` which outputs `CET` should give me my local timezone, which is indeed the correct one on the machine since i'm in UTC+1.
On the UI of Spark also i can clearly see `user.timezone=Europe/Rome`.
Still it looks like spark is trying to convert from UTC+1 to UTC and therefore i get in the output `unix_time_epoch = -3600`, which i instead would expect it to be `unix_time_epoch = 0`.
I've tried to change to UTC as other thread suggest like this:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import time

os.environ['TZ'] = 'Europe/London'
time.tzset()

spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("test") \
        .master(n_spark_master)\
        .config("spark.total.executor.cores",n_spark_cores_max)\
        .config("spark.cores.max", n_spark_cores_max)\
        .config("spark.executor.memory",n_spark_executor_memory)\
        .config("spark.executor.cores",n_spark_executor_cores)\
        .config('spark.driver.extraJavaOptions', '-Duser.timezone=UTC') \
        .config('spark.executor.extraJavaOptions', '-Duser.timezone=UTC') \
        .config('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC') \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()

print(datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo)

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "a"),
    (2, "b"),
    (3, "c"),
], ["dummy1", "dummy2"])

epoch = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
df=df.withColumn('epoch',lit(epoch))
timeFmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
df = df.withColumn('unix_time_epoch',F.unix_timestamp('epoch', format=timeFmt))
df.show()
```

but the output is:

```
GMT
+------+------+-------------------+---------------+
|dummy1|dummy2|              epoch|unix_time_epoch|
+------+------+-------------------+---------------+
|     1|     a|1969-12-31 23:00:00|          -3600|
|     2|     b|1969-12-31 23:00:00|          -3600|
|     3|     c|1969-12-31 23:00:00|          -3600|
+------+------+-------------------+---------------+
```

What i want to achieve is to evalueate everything in UTC regardless with not timezone offset since in Rome where i'm located local timezone shifts during the year between UTC+1 and UTC+2, expected output should be like this:

```
+------+------+-------------------+---------------+
|dummy1|dummy2|              epoch|unix_time_epoch|
+------+------+-------------------+---------------+
|     1|     a|1970-01-01 00:00:00|              0|
|     2|     b|1970-01-01 00:00:00|              0|
|     3|     c|1970-01-01 00:00:00|              0|
+------+------+-------------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `os.environ['TZ'] = 'UTC'` instead of `Europe/London`.

In 1970, the United Kingdom was performing a "British Standard Time experiment" where the timezone of the UK is GMT+1 throughout the year between 27 October 1968 and 31 October 1971. (source: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time#Periods_of_deviation)). That's why you got a time which is 1 hour earlier.

Comment: After trying to adjust the spark configs on both the read and write end of things, this ended up being the only thing that worked for me